HDMI->Thunderbolt alternatives to BMD Ultrastudio 3G?
My computer setup has a thunderbolt dock (Caldigit TS4) which also has USB ports, a DSLR camera with HMDI output (Sony A5100).
I originally had an Elgato Calming 4k which is a HDMI-USB3 device. It was never reliable on my setup, and I couldn't get it to work via the dock.
I then moved to a BlackMagic Design UltraStudio 3G Recorder which is a HDMI-Thunderbolt-3 device. Worked much better and through the Thunderbolt dock too.
I am told that with Thunderbolt, I also benefit from the throughout not struggling with 1080p@30fps or 1080p@60fps, whereas USB-3 apparently struggles.
Question: I had to sell the BMD UltraStudio 3G Recorder, but am now ready to buy another capture device. I'm asking for options, and doing internet searches seems to find no similar HDMI->ThunderBolt devices.
Notes:

I can't use a capture card that I need to install internally like a PC graphics card, I'm using a MacBook pro so it must be a device that connects, rather than installs.

I would prefer a HDMI-Thunderbolt-3/4 that will plug into the dock.

The BMD UltraStudio 3G Recorder has SDI input. I don't need this, and am hoping an alternative device is smaller, cheaper.

I did have another problem with the BMD. It doesn't present as a USB-VC class device and so lots of software would not work with it.


